# EOMONTH equivalent in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a `EOMONTH()` equivalent in Postgresql? If not, how do I select only the last day of the month for any given month and any given year given a time stamp? For example, I have a dataset with timestamps. From those times, I want to select only `2015-01-31`, `2015-02-28`, ... `2016-02-29`, `2016-03-31`, etc. What is an efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 10):

One method is:

```
select date_trunc('month', col) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!